# Paginate Links function: Page 1 doesn't work

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I got this:

```
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => '%_%',
    'format'          => '?listpostspage=%#%',
    'total'           => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => false,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => 2,
    'prev_next'       => true,
    'prev_text'       => __( 'Zurück', 'Theme' ),
    'next_text'       => __( 'Weiter', 'Theme' ),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);
```

Strangely the page 1 link is always the page im currently on? What is wrong?

Comment: Found the answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526711/wordpress-paginate-links-first-page-always-the-same-as-current-page).

Comment: If you had figured out your issue you might want to post it in detail as an answer so that others can benefit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Base is the Problem:

```
'base' => add_query_arg('listpostspage','%#%'),
```

Here ist the full code:

```
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => add_query_arg('listpostspage','%#%'),
    'format'          => '?listpostspage=%#%',
    'total'           => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => false,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => 2,
    'prev_next'       => true,
    'prev_text'       => __( 'Zurück', 'Theme' ),
    'next_text'       => __( 'Weiter', 'Theme' ),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);
```

Thanks goes to [raison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468603/raison) over at stackoverflow who posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549327/2593099).